# reading from a binary file in a length indicator way in C++

Tags: c++, file, binary

How can I properly read from a binary file in a length indicator way?
I'm doing something like this but it keeps giving me weird results:

```
size_t len;
string stuff;

stream.read ((char *)&len, sizeof(size_t));
stream.read ((char *)&stuff, len);
```

I'm writing it this way:

```
ostringstream temp;
temp << p.bee;
string tempbee = temp.str();


size_t len = sizeof(tempbee);
stream.write ((char *)&len, sizeof(tempbee));
stream.write ((char *)&tempbee, len);
```

Comment: You may face endianess problems if you use these files on different machine architectures. Also size your `string` variable before filling in data, and refer to the first `char` address: `&stuff[0]`.

Comment: doesn't seem like a good idea to read into a complex class like `std::string` which might involve memory allocated from the heap...

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look like:

```
size_t len;
string stuff;

stream.read ((char *)&len, sizeof(size_t));
stuff.resize(len,0x00);
stream.read ((char *)&stuff[0], len);
```

---

```
size_t len = tempbee.size();
stream.write ((char *)&len, sizeof(size_t));
stream.write ((char *)&tempbee[0], len);
```

Also expect problems with `len`'s **[endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)**, when transferring these files between different machine architectures.

To solve the endianess problem, you can define a compatibility format for your file (e.g. use always network byte order (aka big endian)) to write the length and use the functions from the [`ntohl()`, `htonl()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) family, to convert to/from the length value.

Comment: I might be wrong (and at least makes me uncomfortable), but doesn't this `&stuff[0]` make assumptions about how `std::string` manages its contents? I was trying to find confirmation from the references, but I couldn't get it. It would require that a) strings must store characters in consecutive memory and b) that the reference returned by operator[] points to that space.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  Did not work. What do you mean by len's endianess?

Comment: @user2949483 perhaps you should show how you're writing the binary file.

Comment: @jsantander I's guaranteed, same as it is for `std::vector<>` (which might be more appropriate).

Comment: @user2949483 I have added a link for more explanation about endianess. I can't tell if this is cause of your problem, without knowing how the file was written. In which way my proposed code _didn't work_?

Comment: @user2949483 Se my update, your writing code was wrong!

Comment: @user2949483 I also added some information to point you, how to solve the endianess problem.